# Load and unload a page into a div from a navigation button

Tags: html

Can anyone tell me in the simplest code possible, how to load and unload an html page into a div named "myDiv", with a simple click?

When i press another button on my navigation menu, i will then unload "myDiv" and replace with another page.

Whats the setup for this?

*edit*

I have 3 pages (page1.html, page2.html, page3.html)

My navigation is as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="page1.html"></a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.html"></a></li>
  <li><a href="page3.html"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to load those pages into "myDiv", each page replacing the previous loaded page everytime i click a different page button. Thats all.

I hope i made what im trying to do clear as crystal and hopefully not leaving anything important out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can use javascript/jQuery (you don't give a lot of info on your environment)...

Have a look at the jQuery load() method.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '#myButton' ).click( function() {
            $( '#myDiv' ).load( 'test.html' );
        });
    });
</script>
```

That should do your load.  I'll leave the rest to you :)

EDIT:

OK, something more along the lines of what you're looking for...

Assuming you can modify the markup and add a class attribute to your a elements...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="page1.html" class="dynamicLoad"></a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html" class="dynamicLoad"></a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.html" class="dynamicLoad"></a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
            e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link

            $( '#myDiv' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );
        });
    });
</script>
```

So any 'a' element with the class of dynamicLoad will trigger this when clicked.  We don't want the browser to try and follow the link, so we use preventDefault() and stopPropagation().  The only other difference is that we're not statically loading "test.html".  We're determining what html page to load by using jQuery's $( this ), which represents the element that triggered the function.  Use the attr() method, which returns the value of a specific attribute of the element.  In this case, the href attribute.

Questions?

Comment: I'm not sure how the edit changes anything?  You have a div on a page, presumably with an id attribute of "myDiv".  when a navigation element is clicked, you want to load an HTML page into that div.  Again, I'm presuming that you want to do it via AJAX.  Assuming all of that is correct, the code above will do what you want.

Comment: ok.... so what about $( '#myDiv' ).load( 'test.html' ); ? 

It appears to me that the page to load is hard coded.  How do I load any page into "myDiv" instead of only test.html?

As it is right now, when i try your code, i click the nav button and a whole new page opens, and not into the div i want.

Comment: Yes, my example is hard-coding test.html into the div.  It was meant to be an example of how to load a page into a div via AJAX.  It wasn't meant to give you exactly what you're looking for.  It's a staring point.  As far as why clicking the nav button loads a whole new page, impossible to say without seeing your code.  Feel free to paste it to jsFiddle and I'll have a look.

Comment: Incidentally, I'll point out that you've been active on SO for a day now, asked 4 questions... received 8 answers, and not accepted any of them.  Please feel free to mark answers "accepted" if they do, in fact, answer your question.

Comment: your latest code seems to do the trick so far. ill let you know if i have any issues

Comment: Glad it's working... but do you -understand- it?  If not, please ask questions and I'll be happy to answer.  I'd rather think you're moving forward understanding what you're working with, rather than just copying/pasting code and not knowing why it's working the way it is.

Comment: Im pretty sure I understand it.  Could you show me how I would write the code for a div button using onClick? I cant use <a href> for the button in my current situation, and every variation ive tried of onclick with this example so far has failed me.

Comment: @charliegriefer: Still needing the solution for this if you can provide it. Trying to throw a div button into the mix in conjunction with the current working code...have it load the page into the div

Comment: Thanks @charliegriefer, u saved my day.